# C++ most efficient way to represent camera covered area in gridmap

Tags: c++, arrays, camera, 2d

I am currently working on a project where a robot is driving through an environment that's represented as a `nxn` gridmap (say `100x100`, but will be way larger in the future) which I'll model as a `2D-array` of `ints`. The area is observed by cameras. The robot knows which camera covers which region and is able to deactivate the cameras remotely from a range that just slightly exceeds the cameras FOV range. It has to come up with a plan to get through the environment unnoticed.

Now, I need to know which area is captured by which camera. Let's assume, for simplicity's sake, that all the cameras have circular FOVs. Now, if e.g. `camera 1` captures a certain region, I though about putting a `1` in that region of the array. So far, so good. But what if there's a second (and maybe third) camera whose FOVs overlap? How would I represent this overlap in the gridmap?

My thoughts so far:

- add up the camera id's in the grid - e.g. if `camera 1` covers a certain FOV, fill it with `1's`. If the FOV of `camera 2` overlaps, fill the overlapping region with `1+2=3`. Drawback: number of possibilities for n cameras is exponential and it will be hard to retrace how a number was calculated - e.g., `6` could be `camera 5` overlapping `camera 1`, but also `camera 2` overlapping `camera 4`.
- concatenate camera id's in the grid - for a overlap of `cam 1` and `cam 2`, put `12` in the grid. For an overlap of `cam 1,2 and 3`, put `123` in the grid. Advantage: integer arithmetic only, should be fast. Drawback: only as many cameras possible as integer range has digits (`int_max` for `32bit` is `4294967295`, so 10 cameras max)

Any help or thoughts? Even literature or algorithms that adress this type of problem? Programming language will be C++.

Comment: Using different bits for different cameras? Camera n, setting bit: `field |= 1 << n;`, clearing bit: `field &= ~(1 << n);` - if operating on single bits, I'd prefer unsigned int then, though. You can manage `CHAR_BIT * sizeof(unsigned int)` cameras that way (on most modern systems, this would be 32).

Comment: Good answer as it will be faster than concatenating the camera id's. Doesn' really solve this approach's drawback though - int_max remains the same, so max. 10 cameras. 
Edit: just saw your edit. good point. any drawbacks you can think of?

Comment: I personally would rather go with the types of `<cstdint>` header, e. g. `uint32_t`. Then you can rely on the exact number of bits. The bit handling requires some few extra CPU cycles - but you shouldn't really notice unless you have some *extreme* performance requirements (occurred to me only one single time in more than 15 years of experience...).

Comment: After thinking some more about this, I suggest you make this an answer so I can accept it as the best answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might use one bit inside your `int` for each specific camera. However, if dealing with single bits, `unsigned int` is preferable: Assuming 32-bit int, `1 << 31` results in undefined behaviour due to signed integer overflow, so you'd have to live with either one bit less or have some special handling for camera ID 31 (assuming zero-based ID):

```
unsigned int field;

// setting the bit for camera ID n (zero based):
field |= 1U << n;

// clearing the bit for camera ID n (zero based):
field &= ~(1U << n);

// reading the bit:
bool isSet = (field & ~(1U << n)) != 0;
```

(Sure, you would pack this into appropriate (inline?) functions...)

This way, you can manage `CHAR_BIT * sizeof(unsigned int)` cameras. On most modern systems, this would be 32 cameras – but this is compiler/architecture dependent! According to the standard, unsigned int is guaranteed to be able to hold the values from 0 to 65535, so to be portable, you only can rely on 16 bits (`long` would assure 32 bits this way, but can be larger, e. g. 64 bits on 64-bit linux). If you want to assure a specific number of bits available, I recommend using the data types from `<cstdint>` header, e. g. `uint32_t` (to be safe that the literal 1U has appropriate range, you should cast then: `static_cast<uint32_t>(1U)` or define a constant of appropriate type).

The bit handling costs a few extra operations, but these should be negligible (apart from some very rare, *extreme* performance scenarios; encountered such one only one single time in more than 15 years of professional experience...).

Just a side note: You might find that bit-fields hide away the bit fiddling from you. Well, sure, they do (but it is still there, just that the compiler does the stuff for you). But they come with other drawbacks then (most important: order of members is not guaranteed to be the same across different systems, so if you serialise them e. g. to TCP or files, you need to be aware of!), I personally would rather avoid them. Still:

```
struct Field
{
    uint32_t  _0 : 1;
    uint32_t  _1 : 1;
    // ...
    uint32_t _31 : 1;
};
```